# Oracle apex set row create username and create datetime on submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have `order` table with these columns:

```
id, customerid, orderdate, createusername, createdatetime
```

`createusername` and `createdatetime` aren't displayed in edit form - I want to set their values on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Set their default values to

- `:APP_USER` for `createusername`
- `SYSDATE` for `createdatetime`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done with a trigger on the table. That way you don't have to worry about this anywhere in your apex application. That trigger would be something like this:

```
create or replace trigger order_biu
    before insert or update 
    on order
    for each row
begin
    :new.createdatetime := sysdate;
    :new.createusername := nvl(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
end order_biu;
/
```

I assumed that the column `order.createdatetime` is of datatype `DATE`. For other datatypes, you'll need another default value.